# PyQGIS expression not working from script but working with GUI

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgsexpression

I'm working on some automation with QGIS. From two polygon layers (buildings and areas) I want to extract the max value of a field in areas touching the building.

So far this is what I have:

```
def export_expression(capa, expresion, directorio, nombre):
    """Given a layer and a QGIS expression, exports the objects that meet the criteria to the specified directory."""
    output = f'{directorio}/{nombre}.shp'
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expresion)
    seleccion = [f for f in capa.getFeatures(request)]
    print(f'Selected features: {len(seleccion)}')
    if not seleccion:
        print('No feature found')
        return

    crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:25829")
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(output, 'UTF-8', capa.fields(), capa.wkbType(), crs, "ESRI Shapefile")

    if writer.hasError() != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        print('Error al crear el archivo shapefile:', writer.errorMessage())
        return

    for feature in seleccion:
        writer.addFeature(feature)

    del writer  

    
    resultado = QgsVectorLayer(output, nombre, 'ogr')
    if not resultado.isValid():
        print('No se pudo cargar la capa exportada.')
    else:
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(resultado)



def edif_nivel(unit, capa_edif, capa_nivel, dir_output, campos_unir=[]):
    """Given a layer of buildings and another one of levels (both polygons), assigns the highest level that intersects with each building. You can specify the fields to join in a list."""

    tmp_edif_nivel = processing.run("native:joinattributesbylocation", {
        'INPUT':capa_edif,
        'PREDICATE':[0],
        'JOIN':capa_nivel,
        'JOIN_FIELDS':campos_unir,
        'METHOD':0,
        'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':False,
        'PREFIX':'',
        'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']
    
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(tmp_edif_nivel)
    tmp_edif_nivel.setName(f'{unit}_tmp_edif_nivel') 
    
    e = u'"level_num" = maximum("level_num", group_by:= "reference")'
    nombre = f'{unit}_edif_level_num'
    print(f'Expresión de selección: {e}')
    export_expression(capa=tmp_edif_nivel, expresion=e, directorio=dir_output, nombre=nombre)


ac11_edif = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('AC-11_edif')[0]

level_num = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('level_num_FASE2')[0]

unit = ac11_edif.name().split('_')[0]



edif_nivel(unit=unit, capa_edif=ac11_edif, capa_nivel=level_num, campos_unir=['level_num','Codigo_unit'], dir_output='D:/gis')
```

My output is 'No feature found', but it get features if I use the same expression ("level_num" = maximum("level_num", group_by:= "reference")) using 'Select by expression' in the Attribute table (in QGIS gui) on the generated 'AC-11_tmp_edif_nivel'.

If I change the expression in my code for something more simple (for example, "level_num" = 60) the code works as intended. I literally have no clue why the code doesn't work with that particular expression that works on the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Need to include a layer scope to the expression context in order to use the aggregate function.

```py
from qgis.core import (
    QgsExpressionContext, 
    QgsExpressionContextUtils,
    QgsFeatureRequest)

def export_expression(capa, expresion, directorio, nombre):
    """Given a layer and a QGIS expression, exports the objects that meet the criteria to the specified directory."""
    output = f'{directorio}/{nombre}.shp'

    # Instantiate a expression context
    context = QgsExpressionContext()
    # Append the layer scope to it
    context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(capa))

    # Instantiate a request
    request = QgsFeatureRequest()
    # Set the filter expression
    request.setFilterExpression(expresion)
    # Set the expression context
    request.setExpressionContext(context)

    # Continue
    seleccion = [f for f in capa.getFeatures(request)]
    print(f'Selected features: {len(seleccion)}')
    if not seleccion:
        print('No feature found')
        return
```